# How to increase size of Http Get Request's Response in Chilkat http

Tags: c#, http, request, response, chilkat

I am using Chilkat Http tp get response from a URL. But whenever the response is too **large**, it either gives **"null" Response** or it gives only partial Page Source. I have gone through Chilkat documentation, but didn't get help. Is there some way to increase the Response Size or if there's any other way to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Either set `MaxResponseSize` to something big enough OR to 0 (which means any size).

see http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csHttpRef.html